# Wireless G vs N Network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Just wondering if anyone could tell me any tips about a router issue.  I previously has a Linksys G network router and ended up having some issues with it as it was getting older.  I went out and bought a new Netgear router, a WNDR 3400.  It's an N network device with a dual band.  The trouble I NOW have is that the Netgear router is slower than the Linksys.  Is this normal with N networks?  I assumed they were faster (due to being newer technology), but maybe I'm wrong?  I did a speed test of both.  Linksys came in at 18.75 Mbps, the Netgear came in at 10.02.   Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have N card in your laptop/computer? Could also be a band issue  have you tried changing the Channel? Do you have other wireless networks around you? make sure you are not on the same channels they are using, etc..

Comment: @Doon I have a new computer so it SHOULD have an N card in it.  It does connect and the internet works, just noticeably slower.  I haven't tried changing a channel yet because I wasn't sure what I should attempt first.  I disconnected the new router and put the old one back on temporarily until I can get some ideas from people.

Comment: @Marcia - do you have latest firmware? http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19827/~/wndr3400-firmware-version-1.0.0.50

Comment: @Carl B I have that downloaded but I don't know what I'm supposed to do with it. It's a CHK extension. It doesn't open with anything on my computer.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the instructions below.  I do not know if this firmware is already in place or not. I will have to try it out. Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Wireless speeds can vary quite a bit between vendors and depends a large number of factors including:

- Distance to router.
- Material between router and client (walls, etc)
- Make of router and client
- Types of devices on the network

The last point might be most relevant to your case. If you have G devices on the same network it will limit the overall rate of the N network.

See these articles at SmallNetBuilder for more information:

- [5 Ways to Speed up Wireless N Speed](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30664-5-ways-to-fix-slow-80211n-speed)
- [Add Don't Replace When Upgrading to 802.11n](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/30224-add-dont-replace-when-upgrading-to-80211n)

Some relevant tips from the 5 ways article:

> **Fix #4: Use WPA2/AES and Enable WMM**
>
> Most 802.11n products will knock your throughput down by up to 80% if
>   you use WEP or WPA/TKIP security. The reason is that the 802.11n spec
>   states that the high throughput rates (link rates above 54 Mbps) can't
>   be enabled if either of those outdated security methods are used.
>
> **Fix #5: Don't use Channel Bonding**
>
> If you are changing the Channel Width or mode from the default 20 MHz
>   to the 40 MHz (or "Auto 20/40" mode in some routers) channel-bonding
>   mode, you could be reducing, not increasing your throughput.